# Gwt localStorageEvent - cross tab communication

Tags: java, gwt, local-storage, session-storage

I want to make cross tab communication. On that i would like to use localStorage / sessionStorage.

Class1 contains this part of code:

```
Storage stockStore = Storage.getLocalStorageIfSupported();
if (stockStore != null) {
    stockStore.setItem("newLoad", "123");
}
```

Class2 contains this part of code:

```
Storage stockStore = Storage.getLocalStorageIfSupported();
    if (stockStore != null) {
          stockStore.addStorageEventHandler(new StorageEvent.Handler() {
          public void onStorageChange(StorageEvent event) {
            Log.println("Heureka!");
          }
        });
    }
```

Code in class one is called when user push button.

So when user have open two tabs and he push button (inside tab 1) which will invoke code in class1. Then event is fired and "Herueka" is written but only in his actual tab (tab 1).
It should be written in both tabs (tab 1 and tab 2). So this is not working.

url of tab 1: http://127.0.0.1:8888/#loads

url of tab 2: http://127.0.0.1:8888/index.html#lights

Tabs have same session and i am using FF 47 for testing.
Everything is compiled trough eclipse local jetty server and super dev mode is used.

Answer (score 2):

One workaround has been found since the previous answer: https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/issues/9205 (I have not tried it)

That said, I have confirmed following to work:

```
private static native void addTrueStorageHandler(Handler h) /*-{
    $wnd.addEventListener('storage', function(e) {
         h.@com.google.gwt.storage.client.StorageEvent.Handler::onStorageChange(Lco    m/google/gwt/storage/client/StorageEvent;)(e);
    });
}-*/;
```

The above function should be called to register the `Handler`. This just creates a javascript anonymous function to call the Handler. It completely bypasses the entire `Storage` GWT mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that and I had the same issues trying to utilize the events on the local storage.
Unfortunately the storage events do not seem to work across tabs.
At least I was unable to have them reliably fire for all tabs and I also needed to exclude the current tab from the event (this tab fired it and does not need to be notified).

What I did as a workaround is to create a class, which handles signaling using the local storage.
It is quite a lot of code, which is tied to an internal project, but I will try to outline how it is done to help you getting started.

I don't rely on events here, but use a [Timer](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/Timer.html) with [scheduleRepeating](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/Timer.html#scheduleRepeating(int)) to periodically check the local storage every 3 seconds.

Every tab needs a different ID, which you can generate e.g. using [Random](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/Random.html).
If I want to signal something I set an entry in the local [storage](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/storage/client/Storage.html).
The key of this entry is the signal name, the value is the id of the tab setting the signal.

So when the [Timer](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/Timer.html) is executed, I check for an entry with the signal name. If I find one, I check the value to be different than the id of the current tab as I don't want to notify the signaling tab for its own event.

*You just need to keep in mind to remove the entry from the local storage on shutdown of your application or after a reasonable amount of time. Otherwise you might encounter the old entry on a fresh start of your application and execute the signal handler again.*

After all it is not perfect as there is always the [Timer](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/Timer.html) running every 3 seconds and the signaled tab can also take up to 3 s to pick up the signal. However it was the only way for me to get a reliable signaling between different tabs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will implement this workaround, but keep question open, because this is not 100% solution for this problem.